# Difference between "> or " /> in HTML

Tags: html, tags

Is there any difference between <...> and <.../>

Very straight forward:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Is there any difference in execution, functions etc.?

Comment: Well `/>` closes the tag.

Comment: I would add specifically for `meta` tags...a `/>` tag is self-closing. (I.e: it's the same as <meta whatever></meta>

Comment: True, But does Meta tag's need it ? Or is it nothing we don'really need anymore

Comment: The question is too vague for constructive answers. Rules vary by HTML version, and the practical difference depends on the software used to process HTML documents and possibly on their mode of operation. If there is a practical difference, it manifests itself so that the document is not displayed at all (only an error message is shown, if the first syntax is used and the document is processed as real XHTML).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

XHTML requires trailing slashes for elements like ("br", "input", "img") whereas in HTML5 they're optional.

See: [Should I remove trailing slashes in meta tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310921/should-i-remove-trailing-slashes-in-meta-tags)

See also: [Does HTML 5 Use a Trailing Slash](http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5tags/f/html5-use-trailing-slash.htm)

Comment: That was what i where looking for. Did not see any difference with or without.

Answer (score 6):

Tags that do not have closing tags in HTML (like `<br>` and `<meta>`) are called *self-closing*.  `<br>` and `<br />` are equally valid in HTML.

However, XML does not permit closing tags to be omitted; `<head><meta></head>` is invalid XML!  The `/` prior to the `>` character indicates to XML that this tag should be immediately closed.  That is, `<x></x>` is semantically equivalent to `<x />` in XML.

You should prefer the form `<br />` when writing HTML code that you want to also be valid XHTML.  If you do not care about XML or XHTML, you can pick which syntax you prefer.

---

Note that `<br/>` is valid XML with the same meaning as `<br />`, but older browsers with parsing bugs would parse that tag as a tag with the name `br/`.  Adding a space in between the tag name and the `/` chararcter satisfies the parsers of defective browsers (who then treat the `/` as an attribute name), while still producing well-formed XML.

Answer (score 4):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

are both valid empty tags in HTML5 while:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

isn't valid in XHTML, because an empty tag such `<br />` tag must be closed with `/` *(slash)* in XML such:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

And remember, always validate your website with: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: validator.w3.org doesn't capture this trailing slash existence in html5, hence it will not report it.

Answer (score 1):

Some tags in HTML are called *self closing tags* and these tags, it's proper code to use `</>`.

An example of a self closing tag would be an input:

```
<input type="text value="someval" />
```

A non-self closing tag would be a paragraph, for example:

```
<p> some text </p>
```

Under certain declarations, however, it's *mandatory* to use self closing tags for certain elements, which is the case when using a *xhtml strict* declaration.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

opens the tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

is the shortform for

```
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
```

Comment: But then does <meta charset="utf-8"> and <meta charset="utf-8" /> achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

"/>" indicates that this is an opening and closing tag for an element, i.e. it contains no whitespace or other elements.

Answer (score 0):

An element with no contents (only attributes) can be "self-closing" by using `/>`. So, for example, an element with content looks like:

```
<p>This is some content</p>
```

With the `</p>` closing the tag. An element with no content, on the other hand, doesn't need a closing tag; you can open and close it in one go with the `/>` shorthand:

```
<img src="myimg.png"/>
```

With no closing tag. Closing tags is optional in HTML5, but required in XML-based formats like XHTML. You can, if you choose, close tags in regular HTML5; this is generally a good idea as it allows your HTML to be parsed by XML processors.

Answer (score 0):

The self-closing tags are obligatory in XHTML, but HTML (especially HTML5) have much less strict rules about them.